# Object literals in [] notation in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two examples . In the first example :

```
a. 
    1. var object = {1 : "value"};

       alert(object[1]);

    2. var object = {1 : "value"};

       alert(object["1"]);
```

In both of the examples , the output is "value". I read in the books that **object[1]** will find a variable `1` and substitute the value with that.
     Since 1 cannot be declared as variable name in javascript `(var 1="some var" //not allowed)` , is it just `alert(object[1])` tries to find the string declared in 
`var object = {1 : "value"};` and alerts "`value`".

Because , there is no difference between 1. and 2. example alerts yield the same result.

```
b.
   1. 
    var object = {a : "value"};

    alert(object["a"]);

        The above example is pretty much clear that it is finding out string "a".

    2. 
    var object = {a : "value"};

    alert(object[a]);
```

The above example is an error , since we havent declared

```
var a = "some";
```

I am just curious to know the difference between **a. 1 and a.2**  and also if my understanding is correct wrt these examples?

Comment: In second example, interpreter is looking for variable `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In both of the examples , the output is "value". I read in the books that object[1] will find a variable 1 and substitute the value with that.

No. It takes a string.

If you pass it a number literal, it converts the number to a string.

If you pass it a string literal, it uses the string literal as a string.

If you pass it an variable then it gets the value of that variable and converts it to a string if it isn't already one.

`1` is not a variable name. The grammar of JavaScript requires that it be treated as a number literal.

> I am just curious to know the difference between a. 1 and 2

In case 1, you are passing a number literal. In case 2, you are passing an undeclared variable. You get a ReferenceError when you try to get a value from an undeclared variable.

You'd get the same effect in any other context where you were doing something with a value.

```
var foo = 1; // Assigns 1
var foo = bar; // Throws a reference error because bar is undeclared
```

Answer (score 1):

Two different things going on.

First, object keys are always strings, but you are allowed to write them without quotes in cases where that doesn't lead to syntax problems.

```
{1: "value"}
{a: "value"}
```

These are other ways of writing

```
{"1": "value"}
{"a": "value"}
```

Even if `a` happens to be a variable, when used like that in an object literal it justs means the string `"a"` and has nothing to do with the variable.

```
var key = "hmm";
var object = {key: "value"}; // object is now {"key": "value"}
```

If you want to have the value of the variable as property, you can use the following ES6 syntax in modern browsers:

```
object = {[key]: "value"}; // object is now {"hmm": "value"}
```

The other thing is what Quentin said; when you lookup a property's value with object[*x*], whatever *x* is will be converted to a string.